# preg_replace to remove IE comment

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

This is my string:

```
aaa <!--[if (gt IE 9)|!(IE)]><!--> <html lang=\"en\"> <!--<![endif]--> bbb
```

and this it what I want:

```
aaa  <html lang=\"en\">  bbb
```

and this is what I get:

```
aaa    bbb
```

what is wrong here?

```
<?php
$content="aaa <!--[if (gt IE 9)|!(IE)]><!--> <html lang=\"en\"> <!--<![endif]--> bbb";
$tagOpen="<!--[if (gt IE 9)|!(IE)]><!-->";
$tagClose="<!--<![endif]-->";
$condition='/'.preg_quote($tagOpen).'.*?'.preg_quote($tagClose).'/i';
$content=preg_replace($condition, '$1', $content);
echo htmlentities($content);
```

---

link: http://3v4l.org/TrO1U

Comment: `'.*?'` should be `'(.*?)'` (otherwise, the is no `$1` subpattern).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't create a capture group. Try:

```
$condition='/'.preg_quote($tagOpen).'(.*?)'.preg_quote($tagClose).'/i';
```